# Google App Engine Endpoint - Unknown error (HTTP Code: 500) coming intermittently

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am getting Unknown error (HTTP Code: 500) intermittently. Also, there is no exception log in Google Developer Console. Kindly help me to resolve this.
Note: My App engine's Endpoint don't have any authentication and it is open to hit.

Following is that intermittent response:

```
500 OK

cache-control:  no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  33
content-type:  text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:  Fri, 11 Sep 2015 13:30:18 GMT
expires:  Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:  no-cache
server:  GSE

Unknown Error
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when you get this response?

Comment: Actually, I am doing a unit-testing from POSTMAN client. When I try to hit same API method more than once, intermittently I am getting this error. Ideally I shouldn't get this error.

Comment: HTTP 500 error code means an internal server error. Usually that would indicate that the problem is not your fault and that there is a bug or some other issue on the server side. Report it to Google.

Comment: Now, this error seems to be stopped. Yes it could be some temp environment issue. If it comes again I will report it to them. @GlenThomas   thanks mate.